# Call Function with input value of generated array list

Tags: javascript, html

When I select a (array) value. I want to call a function that displays the selected value.

How can I do this?

```html
    <input name="car" list="anrede"  />
    <datalist id="anrede"></datalist>

    <script>
      var mycars = ['Herr','Frau'];
      var list = document.getElementById('anrede');

      mycars.forEach(function(item){
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = item;
        list.appendChild(option);

      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event#:%7E:text=The%20change%20event%20is%20fired,alteration%20to%20an%20element%27s%20value%20.) to your input.

```js
var mycars = ['Herr','Frau'];
var list = document.getElementById('anrede');

mycars.forEach(function(item){
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = item;
  list.appendChild(option);
});
document.querySelector('input[name="car"]').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
   if (mycars.indexOf(e.target.value) > -1) {
        console.log('value in array');
   }
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<input name="car" list="anrede"  />
<datalist id="anrede"></datalist>
```

Answer (score 1):

The selected value is shown in the `input` tag when you choose it.
If you want a function which displays it in a different way, do this:
(note: I don't know the way you want to display the value so in this example, I will show you how to display it in a `<p>` tag. Then you will be able to do it however you want)

**The HTML:** add an `id` and `onchange` attributes to the `input`:

```
<input name="car" list="anrede" id="car" onchange="function1();">
<datalist id="anrede"></datalist>
<p id="example"></p>
```

The `onchange` attribute calls the function `function1` when you choose a value.

**note**: the end of the `input` tag is just `>` and not `/>`.

**Now, the javascript:** add the function `function1` to display the selected value

```
function function1()
{
  var val = document.getElementById("car").value;
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = val;
}
```